# Queueing Load Tests in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, soa, load-testing

I'm currently finishing up a project for University that requires us to build an enterprise application using techniques described in Fowlers "Patterns of Enterprise Architecture".

It's your bog standard ASP MVC application which talks to a service layer which talks to a data layer.. etc.

We've also been asked to run several load test scenarios, ranging from 1-25 users. I've created a load test per scenario (1User.loadtest, 5User.loadtest, 10User.loadtest etc..) and I was wondering if there was any way to queue these up and leave them running, rather than starting one, coming back a few minutes later, starting another.. etc.

TL;DR - Anybody know a way to queue load tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load Tests are automatically queued. When running a load test, you can still add a new test. However, you still require to click N times...

another solution is to use the [command line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182588.aspx).

```
> mstest /TestContainer:LoadTest1.loadtest
```